# iMovie is not uploading videos to YouTube

Tags: video, imovie, youtube

When I click File > Share > YouTube (username) a box pops up, but the "next" button is not highlighted and is not clickable. I've also tried to upload the files from the YouYube website but when I do I get this error and a 0% upload:

"We did not recognize the format of this file, but we will try to process it anyway. See this article on recommended formats for more information."

The file extension is `.imovieevent`.

What can I do to successfully upload to YouTube?

Comment: You seem to have 2 distinct issues - 1)If you can't persuade it to share directly to YouTube, then export as 'Apple' instead & upload manually. Check iMovie is correctly logged into your YouTube account [awkward if you have more than one account or even feed/stream] 2)  .imovieevent isn't a movie in that sense - it's iMovie's list of what clips are in the movie, crossfades etc. It's only a few KB in size & is only of any use to iMovie itself.

Comment: So how do i save the file under a different extension?

Comment: File menu > Share > File…  btw, the reason you don't have a 'Next' button could be that you didn't sign into YouTube in iMovie first - it's interactive, no sign in, no upload.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much experience with iMovie, but I would suggest exporting your video, then uploading it to YouTube. In the past I have used inbuilt uploading mechanics and they don't tend to be the most reliable of things.